# How do I iterate over a Constant Vector?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a vector of Student which has a field name.

I want to iterate over the vector.

```
void print(const vector<Student>& students)
    {
    vector<Student>::iterator it;
    for(it = students.begin(); it < students.end(); it++)
        {
            cout << it->name << endl;
        }
    }
```

This is apparently illegal in C++.

Please help.

Comment: Please read about prefix versus postfix increment operator. `it++` should be `++it`, and `it++` is needed in rare cases (i.e. when erasing while iterating).

Comment: Its fairly obvious what the issue is in this case. However, in the future you should include in your question the exact error message the compiler is giving you.

Comment: @user405725: So... I see you do program in ++C! :-)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have two (three in C++11) options: `const_iterator`s and indexes (+ "range-for" in C++11)

```
void func(const std::vector<type>& vec) {
  std::vector<type>::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter = vec.begin(); iter != vec.end(); ++iter)
    // do something with *iter

  /* or
  for (size_t index = 0; index != vec.size(); ++index)
    // do something with vec[index]

  // as of C++11
  for (const auto& item: vec)
    // do something with item
  */
}
```

You should prefer using `!=` instead of `<` with iterators - the latter does not work with all iterators, the former will. With the former you can even make the code more generic (so that you could even change the container type without touching the loop)

```
template<typename Container>
void func(const Container& container) {
  typename Container::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter = container.begin(); iter != container.end(); ++iter)
    // work with *iter
}
```

Comment: I am new to iterators. Can you please tell me which iterators do not like !=  and why?

Comment: @kunjaan: Only random access iterators support ordering (`<`), others do not. For example, std::list has bi-directional iterators, that can only be compared for equality.

Answer (score 20):

Use `const_iterator` instead. An `iterator` allows modification of the `vector`, so you can't get one from a `const` container.

Also, the idiomatic way to write this loop uses `it != students.end()` instead of `<` (though this should work on a `vector`).

Comment: ...but if you ever decide to change to use a `list` or something similar instead, your code won't work. So use the `!=` form.

Answer (score 9):

C++11 style:

```
void print(const vector<Student>& students) {
    for(auto const& student : students) {
            cout << student.name << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Underated answer :)

Comment: Why do you think it's unrelated? This is how you iterate over const vector in C++11.

Comment: I said underrated but misspelled with a single r. Anyway, not telling unrelated.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `vector<Student>::iterator`, use `vector<Student>::const_iterator`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void print(const vector<Student>& students)
    {
    vector<Student>::const_iterator it; // const_iterator
    for(it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++)
        {
            cout << it->name << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void print(const vector<Student>& students)
    {
    for(auto it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); ++it)
        {
            cout << it->name << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this question is not tagged C++0x

Comment: But this is nice to remember us about that feature, maybe encouraging us to switch to C++11. +1