# interator with ++ in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-overloading

Say, I have an iterator

```
vector<int> myVector;
vector<int>::iterator myIt;
for (myIt=myVector.begin(); myIt!=myVector.end(); ++myIt)
{

}
```

what if I use myIt++ instead of ++myIt.

I got this question, when I read 
[How do I iterate over a Constant Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890497/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-constant-vector)
 it says "Please read about prefix versus postfix increment operator. it++ should be ++it, and it++ is needed in rare cases (i.e. when erasing while iterating)." So, I am kind of confused

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-within-a-for-loop-produce-same-output

Comment: @Borgleader Depending on the iterator implementation and optimiser quality, performance might degrade a little bit.

Comment: Please perform _research_ before asking.

Comment: there is a little difference, the post increment have to make a copy for the returned value

Comment: @Angew Semantically speaking: nothing changes. P.S: something something premature optimization, root of all evil, etc

Comment: @Borgleader Then again, premature pesimization is probably worse. There is nothing to be lost by using pre-increment here, and possibly something to be gained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context you use it, the result will be the same. However, the post-incerement and pre-increment operator are different things which basically can be implemented independently.

Comment: Let me clarify it. I got this question, when I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890497/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-constant-vector  it says "Please read about prefix versus postfix increment operator. it++ should be ++it, and it++ is needed in rare cases (i.e. when erasing while iterating)."  So, I am kind of confused