# Struct Vector and iteration C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct, iteration

I have simple question. According to other examples my iteration for is correct but Eclipse throws me errors...
My Function

```
billing::billing(std::istream &is) {
    unsigned day;
    std::string number;
    float time;
    struct call call;
    while (!is.eof()) {
        is >> day >> number >> time;
        call.day = day;
        call.number = number;
        call.time = time;
        blng_.push_back(call);
    }
    for(std::vector<call>::const_iterator it; it = blng_.begin(); it != blng_.end(); ++it)
        // THROWS HERE ERRORS!
        std::cout << it->day << std::endl;
}
```

After compiling he throws me something like that

```
expected a type, got 'call' billing.cpp     
'it' was not declared in this scope billing.cpp 
expected ';' before 'it'    billing.cpp 
expected ')' before ';' token   billing.cpp
invalid type in declaration before 'it' billing.cpp
template argument 2 is invalid  billing.cpp
the value of 'call' is not usable in a constant expression  billing.cpp
type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for           
'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector'   billing.cpp
```

According to this [How do I iterate over a Constant Vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890497/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-constant-vector) topic it should be working but it isn't and I have no freq idea why. When i change this whole std::vectro... to auto it works!

Comment: You went and created an object named `call`, hiding the type's name.

Comment: Ah you are right! I was looking thousand times on it and could not find it lol.

Answer (score 1):

**In `C++11` you can rewrite:**

```
for(std::vector<call>::const_iterator it = blng_.begin(); it != blng_.end(); ++it)
    std::cout<<it->day<<std::endl;;
```

**as**

```
for(const auto& c: blng_)
    std::cout << c.day << std::endl;
```

**Additional Note:**

You should never loop with `eof()`:
[Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

You should really do something like this:

```
while(is >> day >> number >> time) {

    call.day = day;
    call.number = number;
    call.time = time;
    blng_.push_back(call);
}
```

Comment: Oh ye I was translating some parts of code to English and copied it wrong. But the problem was as juanchopanza wrote above. Thanks anyway! :) I rly like the last one! 

Galik Hmm and thanks for EOF note i will read it right away!