# Iterator type for a const object or const object in c++

Tags: vector, types, iterator

I realize I can just type auto instead of trying to figure out the type for the iterator that I am trying to declare below, but the following is throwing an error and I must be getting the type of my iterator incorrect and the function is simply trying to make a map out of a vector but I was wondering what should the type of the following iterator actually be instead of vector::iterator:
Just curious if I didn't want to use auto.

```
void createMapIntToMovie(const vector<Movie> &movieVec) { // function takes a vector of movies
        //and makes inttomovie map out of it(the movieid to movie)

        //1 - get movie id, 2 insert into the map

        vector<Movie>::iterator it = movieVec.begin();

}
```

Comment: Hint: note the `const`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890497/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-constant-vector