# How to get ::iterator of const std::vector<T>

Tags: c++

I want to take `iterator` from `const std::vector<T>`, but cannot find a way to explain that to the compiler. 
This is how could it look like:

```
(const std::vector<T>)::iterator
```

The workaround: typedef or using

```
template<typename T>
using const_vec = const std::vector<T>;
const_vec::iterator ...
```

**Update. std::vector::iterator is example. The question is about C++ syntax.**

Comment: It's no different from `std::vector<T>::iterator`.

Comment: `const_iterator` is probably a better fit..

Comment: Also keep in mind that `auto` is a thing.

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890497/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-constant-vector

Comment: I need to use it in template deduction. Not in simple for loops. Thank you for the answers guys. But I did not describe the usage case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const` qualifier does not change anything about the definition of the type. So the `iterator` type in `const std::vector<T>` is the same as in `std::vector<T>`. Just use

```
std::vector<T>::iterator
```

or, if `T` is a template parameter, making this a dependent name:

```
typename std::vector<T>::iterator
```

You probably don't want `iterator` though, because there is no function of `std::vector<T>` that could return an `iterator` on a `const` qualified instance. You probably want `const_iterator` instead.

Generally you don't need to access the iterator type aliases anyway. You can obtain the correct type from `auto` in a variable definition:

```
const std::vector<T> vec{/* ... */};
auto it = vec.begin();
```

or with `decltype` if you need the type itself:

```
const std::vector<T> vec{/* ... */};
using iterator = decltype(vec.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` like:

```cpp
const std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin();
```

or just take advantage of `auto` like:

```cpp
const std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
auto it = v.begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation [vector.begin()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)